# Servlet + Javasqript, передача переменной из JS в Servlet для дальнейшей обработки

Tags: javascript, servlet

Есть три кнопки, первая при нажатии сохраняет свое значение. При нажатии на вторую, ее значение меняется на сохраненную первую. Все это я сделала. Нужно, чтобы результат передался в сервлет. 
Показываю код, 
HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<div class="qwerty"><input id="abc1" value=" " type="button"  
onclick="ChangeValue(this);" oncontextmenu="handleRightClick1(this); return
false;" /></div>
<input value = "отправить" type = "button" onclick="callServlet()">
</form>
 <br />
 <div class="qwerty"><input value="й"
onclick="SaveValues(this)" type="button"></div>
```

Java:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String word = request.getParameter("word");
    System.out.print(word);
}
```

Javasqript:

```
var newValue = " ";
var word = " ";

    window.SaveValues = function (Value) {
        newValue = Value.value;
    };
    window.ChangeValue = function (Element) {
        Element.value = newValue;
        newValue = " ";
    };

function callServlet(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/GameServlet?word="+word, true);
    request.send();
}



function handleRightClick1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("abc1").getAttribute("value");
    word = word + x;
    alert(word);

};
```

Все работает, кроме того, что переменная "word" так и не хочет перегоняться в сервлет. Помогите, пожалуйста исправить. В функции я сильно накосячила, да и форма(form) как итог бесполезная вышла.

Comment: A если Вы в браузере введете http://localhost:8080/GameServlet?word=123 функция вызывается?

Comment: Да, с вашим 123 все передалось и вызвалось нормально. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте alert или console.log в начале функции callServlet и посмотрите вызывается ли она вообще

UPDATE:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/GameServlet?word="+word); 
request.open("get", url, true);  
request.send();
```

UPDATE2:

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("word"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Поставила алерт на вывод слова, которое хочу передать, функция вызывается. Сканер как итог вывел символы: Ñ. Может быть дело в кодировке?

Comment: какой такой Сканер?

Comment: Боже, что я вам несу. Просто вывела на экран слово word. К вечеру в мозгах уже каша, прошу прощения.

Comment: то есть функция callServlet вызывается? чудеса... должно работать, ошибок в консоли браузера нет?

Comment: Да, я закинула алерт внутрь функции, то есть по факту она вызывается. Почему чудеса? Мой код настолько ужасен? :D
Нет, нигде ошибок нет. То есть все передается, но странными символами.

Comment: То есть до сервера функция дошла, ок, осталось лишь заэкранировать вашу строку, вы же посылаете русский текст?

Comment: Да, сейчас попробую на английском еще

Comment: БОЖЕ!! Английский текст прошел!

Comment: var url = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/GameServlet?word="+word);  request.open("get", url, true);

Comment: Не помогает. Английский текст проходит, русский все равно нет.

Comment: а что приходит когда русский текст? и последовательность заэканирована?

Comment: Обновил ответ, вам надо конвертировать заэкранированную строку обратно

Comment: Ð¹Ñ -  вот такие символы проходят вместо русского текста. Нет.

Comment: Ни в какую. Тоже не работает. Те же самые символы.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27438/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-kira).